# Firebird simple triggers wont be executed (deadlocks/ concurrent updates)

Tags: sql, firebird, triggers

Hi I m working with a local Firebird database (2.5) which is been created and handled mostly programmatically (part of a copyrighted application i have no access to). 
What makes it really difficult is I cant alter tables the app uses at all and more importantly because of its design (nulls/duplicates/general bad structure) I am unable to set up any foreign keys.

What I tried to do instead is create a set of triggers to pick-up data from other tables on insert.

So for example when the app inserts a record of a job with the columns 
**(JOBID, ADDRESS_ID, ...)**
and i want to reference say ADDRESS1 from the ADDRESSES table
So I tried:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER JOBS_FKs FOR JOBS_SQL
ACTIVE before INSERT POSITION 0
AS 
BEGIN 
  NEW.ADDRESS1 =(SELECT FIRST 1 ADDRESS1 FROM SC_ADDRESS WHERE ADDRESS_ID=NEW.ADDRESS_ID);
END^
```

**OR**

```
SELECT FIRST 1 ADDRESS1 FROM SC_ADDRESS WHERE ADDRESS_ID=NEW.ADDRESS_ID INTO NEW.ADDRESS1
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE JOBS_SQL  SET...
```

but I always get: *update conflicts with concurrent update* 
I also attempted  "before insert" "on TRANSACTION COMMIT" to no avail

Am I doing something wrong or is triggers just not the answer at all?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use `UPDATE` in a trigger to update the table the trigger is applied to (as in your third example). However I wouldn't expect a trigger that uses the `NEW` context (as in your first and second example) to cause an update conflict. Are you sure you don't get this error without the trigger (or an empty trigger)?

Comment: You might also want to check if the transactions of the application uses `no_rec_version` as one of the transaction options.

Comment: The error happens when I try to commit the trigger but after what you said I've tried it (the first trigger) on a test database and it went through fine. So it might just be something else causing the conflict. I mean otherwise do you recon such a trigger (presuming it executes at a reasonably small time) could somehow be responsible for blocking or impacting inserts to original table?

Comment: The error you get means that two concurrent transactions attempted to update the same record. BTW: Could you clarify what you mean with "commit the trigger". If this error occurs when committing the database DDL, then it is an entirely different problem than when you get this when the trigger is fired.

Comment: sorry I mean it just doesn't create the trigger. FlameRobin is got this system of checking syntax and then committing the changes

Comment: Turns out its conflicting with an obscure trigger the app uses to post a "Job inserted" event. Firebird still get well confused. Thanks for helping me figure it out

Comment: Good you found the problem; if you are able to reproduce it and it looks like a bug in Firebird, could you please report a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE ?